# Re-installation failed due to different application signatures - AGAIN

Tags: android, installation

I create an APK and install it on the device.  All works OK.

Then I try and run the app from Eclipse and it gives the error above.  I didn't make any changes or even need recompiling. I tried running it as debug as well as release and both have the same errors.

Something is messed up somewhere as this used to work :(

**EDIT: If I want to send out a pre release to users that have a normal install from the market, does that work ok, if I just send them the APK?**

Answer (score 0):

This happens when you for example install or run applications with the same package but signed with two different(may be debug) keys. Just uninstall the application and run it from Eclipse againg.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to uninstall the application (either though the Android App Manager or `apk uninstall <application package-path>`) and then deploy it.  It seems to get confused when you do a proper install then try to deploy a dev build over it.

Answer (score 0):

You may have messed up your debug certificate. Try to remove it from  ~/.android/debug.keystore (Linux/Mac OS X); or %USERHOME%/.android on Windows.

then uninstall using adb your app : `adb uninstall yourpackagename`

And try to launch it again from eclipse.

Answer (score 0):

It is neither necessary nor desirable to perfom an uninstall of the application if, say, you want to preserve user data like settings.

I have had the same problem for a while, and my solution is simply exporting the app (like when publishing, with the release key) and intalling that .apk file on my phone (I attach it to an e-mail and send it to myself).
This will have the same effect as updating it normally through Google Play Store, and all previously saved data is retained.

It may not be as convenient as running it directly from Eclipse, but having to uninstall the application all the time is not such a great solution either.